# Vertically aligning <div> within <div>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a white box centered, both horizontally and vertically, within a div with a background image.

I have managed to center it horizontally as seen below in the "center"-class, but not vertically. I have tried to set "bottom" for the "filter-box"-class to the desired value and tried to use line-height and vertical align - all without the box even moving.

```css
.image-container {
  background: url('stubbe.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  height: 40em;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 20em;
}

.filter-box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="filter-box center">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` and `align-items: center` in your parent element.

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  background: yellow no-repeat fixed;
  height: 40em;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 20em;
}
.filter-box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="filter-box center">
  </div>
</div>
```

I case of need you can center it horizontally with flex too, just add `justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use flexbox to quickly center the div by setting the outer container's display to be flex. This would also negate the need for the `center` class.

```
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('stubbe.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  height: 40em;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 20em;
}

.filter-box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```